# How to capture JmsTemplate failure to connect exception

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am connecting to ActiveMQ using `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and using Spring's `JmsTemplate` for pushing the message. When I try to send message with invalid port or if ActiveMQ is down it doesn't throw exception in present thread and terminates the thread.

```java
public void byPassMessage(String message, String queueName){
    try {
        if (jmsTemplate == null) {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
            connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
            connectionFactory.setUserName(user);
            
            jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
            jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        }
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
        
                  //Continue logging

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //print exception and continue fallback with logic
    }
}
```

If ActiveMQ is down it doesn't come to the `catch` block. Also it doesn't continue to logging part. It simply terminates the thread.

```
2023-03-15 16:45:16.219 WARN 447376 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://*.*.*.*:61610?connectionTimeout=0&keepAlive=true&useInactivityMonitor=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=2] after: 10 attempt(s) with Invalid connect parameters: {warnAfterReconnectAttempts=2}, continuing to retry.
```

I can see this in my console logs but this is coming on different thread "ActiveMQ Task-1".

Comment: How do you know it's terminating the thread? Perhaps it's just waiting in `convertAndSend` while another thread tries to reconnect. Have you acquired a thread dump to see what may be going on when this happens?

Comment: Any feedback here?